# Having an issue with div appearing below another

Tags: html, css

I have two divs.  First acts as a banner of sorts.  The next is just a small div that I'm trying to place directly below the first div.  I've tried taking away **float** and adding **clear: both**.  Perhaps I'm missing something?  Below is my html and css

```
<div id="background">
</div>
<div id="us">
</div>

#background 
{
    width:  100%; 
    height: 10%; 
    position: absolute; 
    left: 0px; 
    top: 0px; 
    border:1px solid #000;
    background-color:black;
    background-image: url(resources/images/****.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    clear: both;
}
#us
{
    display: block;
    width: 165px;
    height: 200px;
    left: 0px;
    align-top: auto;
    position: absolute; 
    background-image: url(resources/images/*****.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

The first div does appear at the top of the page and displays correctly.  The second one appears over top of the first div.  Any advice?

Comment: Remove `position:absolute;` from both divs

Comment: @Jon the second image stays in place.  The first image gets reduced to a line.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out.

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j8Z85/2/)

Just add `top:10%;` to your `#us` because you are using `position:absolute`.
The size of your `top` in `#us` must be the same size with your `height` in `#background`. I also added  `box-sizing:border-box;` for you borders not to take space.

Answer (score 0):

You have used `position: absolute;` in CSS of second `div(#us)` that's why it is showing on top of first `div`. Change that to `position: relative;` or delete that line.
And you are ready to go.

Comment: If I change it to position relative, the div/image disappears  completely.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Correction to above^.  I forgot the semi colin.  However, it is still in the same position.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
#us
{display: block;
    width: 165px;
    height: 200px;
    left: 0px;
    align-top: auto;
    **margin-top: 50px;**
    background-image: url(resources/images/*****.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

Comment: You should maybe merge it with your other answer.